# Creating Multiple Frame Error

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt

In my Inventory  Management System the program creating 2 entry forms for a single click. I can't identify the problem.

**Code of Menu Action Performed**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
    String s=e.getActionCommand();

    if(s.equals("Stock Entry"))
    {
      Store.Stock_Entry.Stock();

    }
   else if(s.equals("Stock Update"))
    {
      Store.Stock_Update.Stock();

    }
}
```

when User Click the Stock Entry Option In the menu it creating 2 form for stock entry.

**Code of Stock Entry Section**

```
 public void MakeGUI(JFrame f)
 {
    Cframe=f;
    l1=new JLabel("STOCK ENTRY FORM");
    l2=new JLabel("Product ID:");
    l3=new JLabel("Product Name");
    l4=new JLabel("Quantity");
    l5=new JLabel("Unit Price");       
    b1=new JButton("Add Product To Stock");
    t1=new JTextField(20);
    t2=new JTextField(20);
    t3=new JTextField(20);
    t4=new JTextField(20);
    Container c=f.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(null);
    c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    f.setSize(600,600);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setVisible(true);
    c.add(l1);
    c.add(l2);
    c.add(l3);
    c.add(l4);
    c.add(l5);
    c.add(b1);
    c.add(t1);
    c.add(t2);
    c.add(t3);
    c.add(t4);
    t4.setBounds(300,300,200,25);
    t3.setBounds(300,250,200,25);
    t2.setBounds(300,200,200,25);
    t1.setBounds(300,150,200,25);
    l5.setBounds(100,300,200,25);
    l4.setBounds(100,250,200,25);
    l3.setBounds(100,200,200,25);
    l2.setBounds(100,150,200,25);
    b1.setBounds(250,450,200,25);
    l1.setBounds(200,100,200,25);
    b1.addActionListener(this);


}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent be)
{
     proid=t1.getText();
     proname=t2.getText();
     proqty=t3.getText();
     prorate=t4.getText();
     prodid=Integer.parseInt(proid);
     productrate = Integer.parseInt(prorate);
     productqty= Integer.parseInt(proqty);
     cost=productrate*productqty;


   con=getUserConnect();

}

public class Stock_Entry
{ 

   public static void Stock()
   {
      Entry en=new  Entry();
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Menu");
  en.MakeGUI(frame); 
   }
}
```

I can't identify the problem. The same code is used in the update section it works perfectly.

Comment: Some advices to get quicker help 1) Try to indent your code. 2) Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating your problem. 3) Follow java code conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you probably added the `ActionListener` twice to your `JButton` by accident, you can check by adding the following you your code:

```
//Add this Line
System.out.println("INSIDE STOCK ENTRY ACTIONLISTENER)
if(s.equals("Stock Entry"))
{
  Store.Stock_Entry.Stock();

}
else if(s.equals("Stock Update"))
{
  Store.Stock_Update.Stock();

}
```

Then try running your program again, and look at the output: if it displays 
"INSIDE STOCK ENTRY ACTIONLISTENER" twice, then you must have accidentally added the `ActionListener`twice to the same `JButton`. 
The reason the update looks normal is because updating/refreshing something twice will remain the same and you are unable to tell.